# Apache http to https redirect with Squid reverse-proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, https, redirection, squid, reverse-proxy

I have a web server that runs website example.com. I have configured http to https redirect on apache; See below

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName www.example.com 
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName www.example.com 
  DocumentRoot /usr/www/htdocs 
  SSLEngine On #etc... 
</VirtualHost>
```

A request on http is redirected successfully Internally.

So the problem is External request they have to go through Squid Reverse Proxy. And when try to connect to http://example .com a http connection is established. Not https, the redirect is unsuccessful.

If we enter the url as http://example.com/index.html, the connection redirects to https successfully.

Does anyone have an idea on how we can sort this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> When trying to connect to `http://example.com`, an HTTP connection is established, not HTTPS and the redirect is unsuccessful.

One issue that you seem to have is that there are no entries for `http://example.com` in your Apache virtual host configuration. The `www` prefix is technically a subdomain of `example.com` and is therefore considered a separate site for resolution. Excluding any issues with Squid, a simple fix would be to modify your virtual hosts to account for the different variations of `example.com` with the `ServerAlias` directive:

```
# Redirect http://example.com and http://www.example.com
# to https://www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

# Serve https://example.com and https://www.example.com
# from the same DocumentRoot

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName example.com 
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/www/htdocs 
  SSLEngine On #etc... 
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that you could also redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`:

```
# Redirect http://example.com and http://www.example.com
# to https://www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName example.com 
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
  SSLEngine On #etc... 
</VirtualHost>

# Serve https://www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName www.example.com 
  DocumentRoot /usr/www/htdocs 
  SSLEngine On #etc... 
</VirtualHost>
```

You can read more about name-based virtual hosts [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did try the suggested solution, and still not working. However after playing around with php, I found that the problem is caused by Squid. Because when I check the protocol for the website via php it show that the connection is https.